# Watching personal 4K videos on Apple TV 4K

Tags: appletv, 4k

It seems I'm not able to watch 4k/60 FPS personal videos on an Apple TV 4K. I put them in photos and while I'm sure they're 4K, I only get to stream HD from my Apple TV 4K.

I have a gigabit connection, so it should be able to stream from wherever.

I also tried to stream from "computers" with family share, but the same videos I made with iMovie are not supported by the Apple TV.

The only 4K videos I am able to watch are the ones bought from iTunes.

Is there a way to watch personal 4K videos on an Apple TV 4K?

[image] <- this file here is played HD on the tv, no matter what I try.

Comment: I tried exporting for itunes, it is bigger, but the quality is just not there. this apple tv really sucks

Comment: What file type are you trying to view? Can you stream other videos you've created, and if so, with what characteristics and file types?

Comment: I am trying to stream these bad boys here from Photos: Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 39169 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 120k tbc (default). they're downsized pretty badly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple limits the resolution of airplay.
You need to install a player and transfer the video to the player documents folder.
Use itunes or imazing, wired  or wireless transmission.Then you can open the video in the player.

Another method is to install a player that supports network sharing, turn on file sharing(SMB NFS DLNA) on the device where the video is located(PC MAC NAS). Mount the network sharing folder, you can stream it at 4K.

Comment: hi, can you suggest a good player?

Comment: @sathia I don't have an Apple TV, all I know is infuse. I don't know if the free version is suitable. Its In-App Purchase is very expensive.

Comment: @sathia VLC is pretty good.

Comment: I installed infuse and so far seems impressive, I can see 4k at 60fps and it's just so good. thank you